# Unable to access internet when using admin credentials on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Our company policy dictates that users must have admin accounts separately from their usual user accounts. We can call them CONTOSO\johndoe and CONTOSO\a-johndoe. The computer is running Windows 10 Enterprise (version 1607) with PowerShell version 5.1.14393.

For testing purposes I'll open two PowerShell windows next to each other, the first just by clicking the PowerShell shortcut and a second one by right-clicking the shortcut, selecting "Run as administrator" and entering CONTOSO\a-johndoe when prompted for credentials.

Now on the normal PS window if I enter

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri www.google.com
```

it instantly returns

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
```

as it should. On the admin PS window it returns the following after around 30 seconds:

```
Invoke-WebRequest: Unable to connect to the remote server
```

I'm unable to determine how the admin-elevated PS is unable to access the internet. So far I've discovered the following:

1. I'm directly connected to internet, no proxies whatsoever in between
2. `netsh winhttp show proxy` shows "Direct access (no proxy server)" on both PS windows
3. I've found no user-targeted GPOs that would cause this
4. I tried creating a local admin account (to bypass possible GPOs) but the result was the same

Any ideas what I might've missed or what to test and how?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't by design and implemented on the firewall(s) by the network team? I just left an environment where the admin accounts were denied internet access by the firewall. If you need to run Powershell commands and/or scripts against local and cloud (e.g., Azure, Office 365) resources, that may be a problem that you'll have to address if I'm right about this. Check with your team, supervisor, and/or network team, if you haven't already, to make sure this isn't intentional.

Comment: It crossed my mind that it could be, yes, but when connecting the laptop directly to public internet (e.g. mobile wifi-hotspot or home connection) with no VPN or such active the problematic behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: If there are no other teams and/or other admins, then it's definitely a problem to sort out. If there are any other IT people at your organization, IMHO your next step is to verify this is not the intended behavior, regardless of how it's implemented.

Comment: You could solve this by asking ”Why does admin need internet access?”

Comment: @ToddWilcox I confirmed with the team responsible for workstation administration that this isn't intended behavior and they were otherwise unaware of this as well. The workstation team might not have the best knowledge of the network however, that's why I tested it in another, public, network too.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor To install PowerShell modules from PSGallery's repository.

Comment: "**The workstation team might not have the best knowledge of the network**" So why did you check with them? At this point, anyone here at ServerFault could be justified in wondering if your question is on-topic, since questions seeking to circumvent security controls are not on-topic. The workstation team (as you yourself point are) are not the correct team to ask about this. Your supervisor would be a good person to ask. Any other server admins would be good to ask. And anyone on the network team would be good to ask. Have you put in a ticket in your internal ticket system?

Comment: "So why did you check with them?" -- Because they manage the user and workstation policies put in place for restrictions like this and I wanted to know whether this was intentional or not. They said no so that line of investigation is ruled out now. I don't see how the company network could affect this when I can reproduce the problem outside it (if I couldn't then that would be a logical way to investigate).

Comment: Also, I'm doing problem investigation for which my supervisor is fully aware of, I'm not here to ask ways to circumvent company security policies.

Comment: @lapingultah that is the scenario that I thought of, after I left for lunch. I am not a Microsoft's Windows expert, but on Debian you can download the package as one user or on a different machine, ensure that they are in the correct place, then install them as admin.

Comment: IME the workstation teams don't know everything about the workstations either. The server teams often are pushing out GPOs and other things that are meant to control the access of the members of the workstation teams also, so they are really not the right team to go to. Have you run `gpresult` or RSOP to see what **machine targeted** policies are applied?

Comment: Do you have access to any other machines? Do they have the same problem? Have you checked to see if any other users can access the internet on the same computer using their admin accounts? If you open a web browser as admin is it also unable to access the internet? Have you checked anti-virus and/or software firewall settings?

Comment: Other machines have the same problem / unintended behavior, yes. Users are not able to access the internet with admin-elevated programs. Disabling antivirus and/or Windows firewall makes no difference. I've combed through effective (regular user and admin) policies - both user and computer - but haven't found a cause for this. Then again I do not know the function of every single GP setting so I might be missing something, I just don't know what exactly. Moving the workstation / user to an OU where GPOs don't apply or inherit won't get me further because the policies have been applied already.

Answer (score 1):

We're using a web proxy that requires authentication, and I find I have the same behaviour in Windows 10.

I have found this to be a workaround, in an elevated PowerShell window:

```
$req = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create("https://www.google.com") 
$req.Proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy 
$req.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
```

After this, I find that other web requests authenticate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using a proxy, you're probably running into the "first-run" issue with IE for the admin accounts. You can either switch to `-UseBasicParsing` to just use the .NET web client instead of IE, or use one of the methods detailed below to `DisableFirstRunCustomize` or equivalent.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005341/the-response-content-cannot-be-parsed-because-the-internet-explorer-engine-is-no